# rails 4 how to use foreign key and primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to set the following association:

```
class Midatum < ActiveRecord::Base
 # ..., diagn1, diagn2, diagn3
 # sample data:
 #  ..., "0123", nil   ,"0124"
 #  ..., "0123", nil   ,"0124"
 #  ..., "0123", "1123", nil  
 belongs_to :icd9, :foreing_key => :diagn1
 belongs_to :icd9, :foreing_key => :diagn2
 belongs_to :icd9, :foreing_key => :diagn3
end

class icd9 < ActiveRecord::Base
 # icd9, description 
 # sample data:(unique)
 #"0123", "some text"
 #"0124", "some other text"
 #"1123", "description text"
 #"1133", "description text"
 has_many :midata, :foreing_key => :icd9, :primary_key => :icd9
end
```

This does not work. It may be obvious for someone but not for me. The database
 is a legacy DB and readonly. I need to establish this assoc to able to work with the data.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from a Rails expert and it does solve my problem. I am posting it in case someone else have the same problem.

```
belongs_to :icd9_a, :foreign_key => :diagn1, :class_name => "Icd9"
belongs_to :icd9_b, :foreign_key => :diagn2, :class_name => "Icd9"
belongs_to :icd9_c, :foreign_key => :diagn3, :class_name => "Icd9"
```

But that means you'll need to query the association using all three methods:
    m = Midatum.first
    m.icd9_a
    m.icd9_b
    m.icd9_c

In the same way, over in the Icd9 class you'll need three separate associations with unique names:

```
class Icd9 < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.primary_key = :icd9

 has_many :midata_a, :foreign_key => :diagn1, :class_name => "Midatum"
 has_many :midata_b, :foreign_key => :diagn2, :class_name => "Midatum"
 has_many :midata_c, :foreign_key => :diagn3, :class_name => "Midatum"

end
```

Note also that since the icd9 table doesn't have an 'id' column but uses the 'icd9' column as the primary key, you'll need to set it as I've done:

```
 self.primary_key = :icd9
```